# Data type to store multiple values in same row

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, collections

I have the data in string form like

```
alpha, beta, gamma
delta, mu, qwerty
```

Which data structure should be used so as the value alpha, beta, gamma remain in the same index?
List or Arraylist?
Share the syntax please.

Please note that alpha, beta, gamma,.... May go to n.

Comment: `List` is an interface. `ArrayList` is an implementation of that interface. I mean you can do this `List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: If your question is about the difference of `List` and `ArrayList` Peteef pointed you in the correct direction. Should that not be your actual problem please edit your question. Currently it's unclear what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArrayList`.

Java ArrayList class uses a dynamic array for storing the elements. It inherits AbstractList class and implements List interface.

The important points about Java ArrayList class are:

- Java ArrayList class can contain duplicate elements.
- Java ArrayList class maintains insertion order.
- Java ArrayList class is non synchronized.
- Java ArrayList allows random access because array works at the index basis.
- In Java ArrayList class, manipulation is slow because a lot of shifting needs to be occurred if any element is removed from the array list.

#### Syntax:

 `ArrayList al=new ArrayList();//creating old non-generic arraylist`

Similarly, You can create ArrayList of String type.

`ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();//creating new generic arraylist`

#### Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
  ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();//Creating arraylist  
  list.add("Ravi");//Adding object in arraylist  
  list.add("Vijay");  
  list.add("Ravi");  
  list.add("Ajay");  
  //Traversing list through Iterator  
  Iterator itr=list.iterator();  
  while(itr.hasNext()){  
   System.out.println(itr.next());  
  }
```

Since You are adding items of string type so You can use
 `ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();//Creating arraylist`.

In your case you can write:

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
  ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();//Creating arraylist  
  list.add("alpha");//Adding object in arraylist  
  list.add("beta");  
  list.add("gamma");  
  list.add("delta");  
  //Traversing list through Iterator  
  Iterator itr=list.iterator();  
  while(itr.hasNext()){  
   System.out.println(itr.next());  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array

Syntax-

*datatype arrayName[] = new datatype[value]*

Example in your case-

```
1)String arr[] = new String[n]// where n is the number of value you have to give
```

and assign it like this-

```
arr[0] =" alpha";
arr[1] = "beta";
```

and so on...

```
2)String arr[]={"alpha","beta",and so on..};

3)by using for loop

for(int i =0;i<=n;i++)//where n is no of values you want to give
{
  String arr[i]=sc.next();// if you have imported Scanner class
}
```

Hope this is what you want